# Windows 10 Slow boot time. Try To debug using Windows Performance Analyzer

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, wpa

I recently upgraded my PC.
I was happy that everything is working and working fast with no errors apart from the long boot time.
Though this is a small price for me to pay I'd rather try and fix this too.
I am trying to figure out what causes this long boot delay.
I also use Acronis boot manager. This is a pre boot sequence which happens before windows boot starts. The recording I refer to happened after the acronis boot.
It also fits the actual time measurements I did  which excluded the initial acronis loader.
I counted the time it takes for the initial ‘boot turning dots’ and it fits the Boot Main Path time which is ~52sec.
Part of this is due to autochk.exe (14 seconds) which keeps running every time.
But I don’t understand what happens between Boot-Pre_fetch to Boot-sessioninit-phase? These are 21 seconds.

Basically I’d like some guidance here as to what I should do/try

1. Why does the autochk.exe starts all the time and why does it take so long?
   I’ve already tried to disable it using 
   chkntfs /X C: D: E: F: (all my drives) and I see that under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager the autocheck for these drives is disabled
2. What happens between Boot-Pre_fetch to Boot-sessioninit-phase? Which process is causing the delay as i can't find anything in the report.
3. Is it normal that the memory usage is at 100% from boot start to winlogon? See the 2nd snapshot.
4. What are the 'unkown items' in the Disk Usage report (e.g. 4 sec usage in the last snapshot)

I have coreI7, Asus PRIME H370 MB, Geforce 1080TI
Another input is that I have 2 SSDs and 3 HDD connected to my PC as well as multiple USB devices
I’ve uploaded the recorded boot here:
[link to boot recording](https://drive.google.com/open?id=139_B6BVHaRen79Fea7ej5UqdFR_dnBvS)

Thanks for any help.

List of attached images:
[delay during boot main path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWQSL.png)

[generic events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkrll.png)

[deep analysis - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujamW.png)

[excessive memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba8HC.png)

['unkown items' in the Disk Usage report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PxzJ.jpg)

Comment: Does this happen after boot in Safe mode, shutdown, normal boot?

Comment: @harrymc  

I haven't tried safe mode. I can try in a few hours.  
It happens during reboot.  
I disabled the windows fast boot feature and i see no traces of hibernation.  
I also tried diagnostic reboot rebooting after disabling all none windows services and disabling all statup entries in task manger.  
I have no recording for this but it took the same time form the minute the windows wheels starting turning until the blue login screen appeared.

Comment: Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.

Comment: ...I added @harrymc   
Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, this is it.

Comment: @harrymc  
I've uploaded a zipped version of the recording as well.  
It is much smaller

Answer (score 0):

I scanned all my hard drives for errors but the scan showed no errors.
However, the fact that 'autochk.exe' starts all the time despite the fact that I’ve already disable checks using chkntfs /X C: D: E: F: led me to try something else.
I disconnected all my hard drives and all usb devices apart from the  boot drive.
With only one drive Boot Main Path took less than 20sec
I then reconnected all the drivers - one by one and the problem did not reappear.    \

Windows performance Analyzer initially showed that the delay was related to  'autochk.exe' which was very helpful.